# trying to get Wimax drivers , i get error "ImportError: No module named gudev"

Tags: python

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gudev

client = gudev.Client(['rfkill', 'net'])

for dev in client.query_by_subsystem('net'):
    if dev.get_sysfs_attr_as_int("type") != 1:
        continue

    driver = dev.get_driver()
    if not driver:
        parent = dev.get_parent()
        if parent:
            driver = parent.get_driver()

    print type, dev.get_name(), driver, dev.get_sysfs_path()
```

but on the host ( ubuntu) i get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gudev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gudev is already the newest version.
```

Comment: Is it installed for the version of python you are using and in the correct path? Maybe pip install it or see where the package details of the deb put the script.

Comment: sudo pip install python-gudev
Downloading/unpacking python-gudev
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-gudev: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (python-gudev does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-gudev when looking for download links for python-gudev
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-gudev
No distributions at all found for python-gudev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you run the following commands I bet you will find your answer::

```
python --version
apt-cache showpkg python-gudev
```

I believe that you have multiple python versions installed and python-gudev is being installed for the one that is currently not set as the current alternative::

```
update-alternative --list python
```

If this isn't it, please supply your version of Ubuntu and the output of those commands.

Comment: i took the shortcut, and installed ubuntu 10.11 Desktop, and then did apt-get install python-gudev, and it gets installed

Answer (score 1):

**To get the driver for Wimax installed on Ubuntu 11.10 , just type the following using the Terminal:**

To open Terminal: Ctrl+Alt+T

Type in the following commands:

**#   sudo apt-get update**

**#   sudo apt-get install madwimax**

*Have fun!!!*